# How to display Kendo Template information from detailRow

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid "detailTemplate" almost identical to this example: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

When my expand icon is clicked, I fetch the data and display another kendo grid just like the orders tab in the above example.

This is working well, as expected.

The problem.

When I fetch the detail data, I also want to display additional info right next to the detail grid. This additional info does not belong in the grid, but I do want it to display next to the grid.

I am doing the following in the detail grid datasource.

```
My Psuedo Code
<script id="template-details">
  <div class="myDetailGrid"></div>
  <div id="additionalInfoTemplate"></div>
</script>
 ...
 detailRow.find(".myDetailGrid").kendoGrid({
 dataSource: {
    transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                axios.post(myUrlString, payloadContent).then(function (response) {
                    options.success(response.data.orders);

                    var templateString = `<div>#: additionalInfo1 #</div><div>#: additionalInfo2 #</div> ....`
                    var template = kendo.template(templateString);
                    var result = template(response.data.additionalInfo);
                    $("#additionalInfoTemplate").html(result); 
                })
            ...
            }
        }
        ...
```

Here is what happens:

-my parent grid displays fine

-when the expand icon is clicked, the details grid displays fine. the detail grid always displays fine when any row is expanded

-The additional info will display fine for the first detail choosen,

-But when the next detail is expanded, the detail grid is correct but the additional info template data is wrong.
It's the previous detail's additional info or blank.

-The additional info is never right after the first row is expanded.

How can I display additional information correctly in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @NigelK said, you shouldn't add multiple elements with same `id` to your DOM. I will suggest something to fix it, but I'm not sure as I can't test it. Here it goes:

- Change the `id` attribute to `class` in your div:

  ```
    <div class="additionalInfoTemplate"></div>
  ```
- Bind the `detailRow` to your `read` function in order to have its reference inside the `post()` callback:

  ```
    read: function(detailRow, options) {
        axios.post(myUrlString, payloadContent).then(function (detailRow, response) {
            ...
            $(detailRow).find(".additionalInfoTemplate").html(result); 
        }.bind(null, detailRow))
    }.bind(null, detailRow)
  ```

Comment: That did it. I changed the id to class, then added $(detailRow).find(".additionalInfoTemplate").html(result);  This works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Your detail template renders a div with the id "additionalInfoTemplate". The problem is that after expanding the second row you now have two divs in the DOM with the same id. Inspect with the browser tools to confirm.

I would expect the first one you expanded to always get the update although it sounds like that's not always the case.

Regardless I think you need to find a way to uniquely identify each div so you can target the correct one. I appreciate this is not a complete solution to your problem but hopefully it's enough to help you progress.